# Audio captions not showing WebVTT

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, webvtt

I'm trying to display my captions with my audio, and it seems like chrome loads it, but i dont see it on the screen, maybe it's because it's at the bottom of the div body?

I see the controls on the screen, but i don't see the audio.

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="" src="data/audio/Voice 006.m4a">
        <source type="audio/m4a">
        
        <track src="data\audio\subtitles.vtt" kind="captions" srclang="en" label="English" default="">
      

        
    </audio>
```

This is my .vtt file

WEBVTT

1
00:00.000 --> 00:02.111

- Hi my name is sam

2
00:02.888 --> 00:06.555

- I wanna see what letter names, letter sounds and words you know.

3
00:07.111 --> 00:10.555

- Let's answer some questions together and see how you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<audio>` element [does not directly support WebVTT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#accessibility_concerns).
One option is to play your audio using a `<video>` element, which does support WebVTT.